# have full width home page in html

Tags: html, css

I have a page which is scrollable to right and left in html.

I don't want it like that.

What I want is my cup and the book be visible without scrolling and a background-image in the center.

```
  <div class="container maindiv " >    
    <img class="img-responsive book" src="http://i.imgur.com/dLCTiyn.png">
    <img class="img-responsive cup" src="http://i.imgur.com/AULhYEH.png">
  <div class="black_bg">
    <ul class = "menudiv">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  <div class= "para">
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p>    
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p> 
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p> 
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p> 
 </div>    

    <div class= "para1">
   <p >
     lorem ipsum
   </p>    
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p> 
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
   </p> 
   <p>
     lorem ipsum
    </p> 
 </div>     
 </div> <!--black_bg-->
</div>
```

The cup and book image be on the right and left of the background image.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL9raxfL/3/) for the same.

Please suggest.

Comment: are you looking like this.? **http://jsfiddle.net/tL9raxfL/9/** or please be clear about your requirement

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tL9raxfL/10/

Answer (score 1):

Try this classes on CSS:

```
.cup{
    height:167px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 134px;
    z-index:1000;
}

.book{
    height: 167px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 134px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: this will hide the cup and book images.

my actual app is more complicated and have more stuffs than the fiddle.

Comment: I don't want it to be scrollable as I said. If you see my fiddle and yours, it is still the same

Comment: it is scrollable because main div has: `width:950px;`

Comment: you still have the `z-index` as 0 in fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94282/discussion-between-sebastianbrosch-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this you have to use the `position:fixed` for the both images and give them valid `left` and `right` `position` as:

```
.cup{
     height: 167px;
     position: fixed;
     //left: -158px;
     top: 134px;
     z-index: 0;
 }

.book{
      height: 167px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0px;
      top: 134px;
      z-index: 0;
 }
```

and here is the working demo

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tL9raxfL/9/)**

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/tL9raxfL/13/

```
.cup{
 height: 167px;
position: fixed;
//left: -158px;
top: 134px;
z-index: 0;
}

.book{
 height: 167px;
position: fixed;
right: -200px;
top: 134px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: nope, where's the book. The book is not visible in your fiddle.

Comment: - Updated the fiddle- check it now